# Search range of cells not returning a specific text from a formula, then copy and paste value to lock result

Tags: vba, search, copy, paste

I am attempting to write a simple macro and assign it to a button to simplify a task for colleagues even less IT literate than I.

I have a range of cells `K,47:W,52` these cells have a formula in

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K$46),"N/A",IF(K$46<TODAY(),SUM($W$69),"N/A"))
```

What I need to do now is write a macro to search that range of cells for values that do not equal `N/A` then copy and **paste value** in the same cell such that the returned value is locked.

I have worked out how to create a button and confident I can assign the macro to it once written.

I have modified macros in the past, but never started from scratch so a little unsure where to go from here.

Comment: `For each c in range("K47:W52").cells: If c.value<>"N/A" Then c.value=c.value: Next c`